# What happens If I execute the nvm install script twice in a row?

Tags: nvm

I executed the nvm install script twice in a row by accident in the macOS terminal.
Does it install the updates only or the total packages again?

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script downloads the total packages again

```sh
{ # this ensures the entire script is downloaded #
....
} # this ensures the entire script is downloaded #
```

(The whole script is based around these brackets, which means that the script downloads it again.)

Comment: Thank you! So, does it mean that it has installed two nvm packages of the same version?

Comment: **If it happend quickly after each other, then yes.** But if you waited a few days between running it again, there could've been an update.